# Pandas DataFrame with values containing ";"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to open a csv file using Pandas, but I can't because of how the rows are structured. Here's a example:

```
10514";"BR";"Abaco";"976";"Insect;Repitile";"III";"12367
```

There's two problems:

- The first and last values have don't have double quotes before and after, respectively
- There's columns that a value can contain ";", which is the csv separator too

Inspecting the csv, I found that it's decoded with 'cp1252'. Here's how I'm trying to open the csv:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(f'{local_path}/df_pf.csv', engine= 'python', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', header=0)
```

And here is the error it's returning:

> pandas.errors.ParserError: ';' expected after '"'

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: try `sep='\";\"` and probably `quote=False`.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code, You can try this  -

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('df_pf.csv', engine='python', 
                        encoding='cp1252', sep=';', quotechar='"', 
                        escapechar='\\', 
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                        header=None)
```

And you can remove the double quotes from values by iterating and replacing the double quotes -

```
for col in dataframe.columns:
    dataframe[col_name] = dataframe[col_name].str.replace('"', '')
```